# How to check if char is in a double char array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have the array in JAVA:

```
public static char array[][] = new char[3[3];
```

during running the program this array fills some characters.
How can I check if this `array[3][3]` has the character' '(space) then `return true`?
Thanks.

Comment: With a compound for-loop...?

Comment: You mean a space in any of the array elements, or just element 3,3 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure element [3][3] doesn't have the character.

Comment: I mean in any of the array elements, if one of them has ' ' - the method must return true.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really try something ?

```
public boolean check(char[][] array){
  for(int i=0; i<char.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<char[i].length; j++){
      if(char[i][j] == ' ') return true ; 
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I advice you to read some algorithm tutorial, it's the base !!